# Change back redirection from product detail page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, product-urls, redirection

I want to change the "Back" URL for the admin's product form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to overwrite this file: **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Back.php**

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Back" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Back" />
</config>
```

**app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/Back.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Back as ParentBackButton;

/**
 * Class Back
 */
class Back extends ParentBackButton
{
    /**
     * Get Button Data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Back'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'back',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Get URL for back
     *
     * @return string
     */
    private function getBackUrl()
    {
        if ($this->context->getRequestParam('customerId')) {
            return $this->getUrl(
                'customer/index/edit',
                ['id' => $this->context->getRequestParam('customerId')]
            );
        }
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/'); // Update your url here
    }
}
```

> After creating the above file please run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento cache:clean
```